# Can't receive the value of selectec item from Radio Button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So, I'm trying to do a online pool but I cant receive the value of selected item...
If someone can help me here is my Controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Vote(int id, string text)
    {
        using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
        {
            var Voted = new Vote();
            var queq = new Answer { Id = id, Text = text };

            //    var Question = await poolDbContext.Questions.Include(s => s.Answers).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            var Question = await poolDbContext.Questions.Include(A => A.Answers).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == r.Id);

            if (Question == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(Question);
        }
    }

           [HttpPost, ActionName("Vote")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult VotePost(Question question)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
                {
                    var id = question.Id.ToString();
                    var qId = question.Id;
                    var selectedAnswer = question.SelectedAnswer;

                    poolDbContext.SaveChanges();
                    // Save the data 

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            return View(question);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " + "Try again, and if the problem persists " + "see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And also here are my Question Model:

```
    public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }

}
```

Here is my Answer Model:

```
 public class Answer
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my Vote Model

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IpAdress { get; set; }
    public DateTime VoteDate { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { set; get; }
    public Vote()
    {
        Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
}
```

My objective right now is to receive the vote from the Vote.Cshtml by the way here it is :

```
    @model PoolManager.Models.Question
<div>
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
   <h3> @Model.Text </h3>
  @foreach (var a in Model.Answers)
  {
    <p>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.SelectedAnswer, a.Id)  @a.Text
        @Model.SelectedAnswer
    </p>
<input type="submit" />
}
```

So my objective is to receive the vote for each question and add the vote to the db, I don't know what i'm doing wrong..

Comment: well your view doesn't appear to include a form, unless you've missed out some code? You've got a submit button, but no form enclosing the buttons and the controls. Also why does your Post request accept a single answer as an extra parameter, when the Question model already includes a list of possible answers

Comment: And you can delete the `Answer answer, int QuestionID, int AnswerID, string Voted` parameters from your POST method - they are pointless since you are already binding to your model. And you `var selectedAnswer = answer.Id;` makes no sense (you are binding to your `SelectedAnswer` property and that code would throw a exception anyway)

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you make a sample code of how should I do this ?

Comment: Assuming you do have a form in the view, and it does post back to that method, then because you have generated form controls for `Id` and `SelectedAnswer`, then you `Question` will be bound with those 2 values in the POST method.

Comment: And you also need to get rid of the `Question question, Answer answer, Vote vote` parameters in the GET method. You do not have multiple complex objects as parameters in GET methods. All you should have is a `int id` parameter which will be the ID of the `Question` you want to display

Comment: @StephenMuecke already removed them

Comment: @StephenMuecke but can you make an example, because it's still not working... please

Comment: @ADyson I already added a form to my view, still not working

Comment: please edit the question to show your changes, then we can be sure of precisely what you've done. Also, when you say "not working", what exact behaviour are you experiencing? Does the POST request succeed, but just the model does not serialise? Or do you get some other error?

Comment: @ADyson I've already eddited t the question, the get method works perfectly but my post doesnt retrive any value, everything is null...
But no error's

Comment: you don't appear to have removed the redundant parameters from the Post method, which Stephen has mentioned. And you're still trying to make use of them as well (e.g. using answer.Id) even though we've explained that they will never be populated.

Comment: As already mentioned, the values you want, if anywhere are likely to be in question.Id and question.selectedAnswer, since these are the only fields which appear on your form.

Comment: @ADyson  already changed my post method

Comment: and I have removed what Stephen has sed from Get

Comment: Stephen said "And you can delete the Answer answer, int QuestionID, int AnswerID, string Voted parameters from your POST method". You haven't done that. Or not entirely. You're still left with `Answer answer` and `Vote vote`, neither of which will ever be populated because your form doesn't contain those fields. You do understand that your fields have to be on the form and be submitted? They don't just magically appear from nowhere because you want them to. The **only** fields in your form are `Id` and `SelectedAnswer`, both of which will be submitted as part of the `question` object.

Comment: @ADyson ok ok I understand it now, already changed that

Comment: I'm always getting value of 0 on my post.. Please help